# How to make CPAN Testers load a development release of a prerequisite?

Tags: perl, automated-tests, cpan

I recently uploaded development releases of two distributions to CPAN where one depended on the other. Let's say one distro is named `Distro`, the other `Prereq`, and `Distro` requires `Prereq` version 0.009_001.

Unfortunately, I didn't get any test reports for `Distro`. I think the reason is that the versions of dev releases simply aren't tracked by CPAN. They don't appear in `02packages.details.txt`, so CPAN thinks that the dependency can't be satisfied.

Is it impossible to make a CPAN Tester load a development release of a prerequisite? Or is there a work-around?

Comment: I do sympathise, but there are good modules and bad modules. It sounds like you know how to fix your problem, so it doesn't look like you have a specific programming question

Comment: @Borodin I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I think you will get better answers in #toolchain on irc.perl.org. The usual suspects don't frequent SO.

Comment: @nwellnhof can you provide specific informations about `Prereq` and `Distro`?  Dev releases *are* supposed to be *tracked* by CPAN and should enter the Cpantesters process.

Comment: @smonff AFAIU, dev releases are only tracked in CPAN's [RECENT](http://www.cpan.org/RECENT) file which is used by CPANTesters, but they're not listed in 02packages.details.txt which is used to resolve prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

While some CPAN Testers might just happen to have that development release already installed when they test your distribution, most probably won't, and there's no way to require that they do have it.

If the prerequisite is Pure Perl, it is probably possible to bundle an entire copy of the prerequisite library in a `./t/bundled/` directory of your distribution, and then in test scripts include this near the top to force the bundled version to be loaded by automated testers:

```perl
use FindBin '$Bin';
use if $ENV{AUTOMATED_TESTING}, lib => "$Bin/bundled";
use Name::Of::Prerequisite;
```

(I do something similar not with CPAN Testers, but with Travis continuous integration, forcing it to test against the latest checkout from GitHub of certain prerequisites.)